Probability a set of students pass a Test

Given that the first row is a grouped data revealing the scoring of the students and the second row the probability of getting that range of scores, if the minimum score for entrance is 600, if we choose 20 random students what is the probability that 3 students enter the university
I was trying:
$$P(X=3) = \binom{20}{3}(0.01)^3(1-0.01)^{17}$$
Is that correct?

You have the right idea but the wrong number.  The probability that a randomly selected student scores at least $600$ is $0.10$, not $0.01$.  So the correct probability that exactly $3$ students out of $20$ meet this requirement is
$$\Pr[X = 3] = \binom{20}{3} (0.10)^3 (1 - 0.10)^{17}.$$
But if the question is whether at least $3$ students meet the requirement, you would need to calculate
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X \ge 3] &= 1 - \Pr[X \le 2] \\
&= 1 - \binom{20}{0}(0.1)^0 (0.9)^{20} - \binom{20}{1}(0.1)^1 (0.9)^{19} - \binom{20}{2}(0.1)^2 (0.9)^{18}.
\end{align}$$
